# PHP Secure Remember Me for Login using PHP Session and Cookies with referer url

Tags: php, authentication, pdo

I have followed a mysqli tutorial to create a login with cookies and session with remember me authentication in pdo.

in tutorial class had a new `db_connection`, I tried to inject my pdo connection in to class, same as in here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo and read some answers in stackowerflow by `Your Common Sence` and `dharman` answers for injecting pdo connection in to class.

I was getting errors on it, so I changed it to `global $pdo;`.

I need your reviews and your reccomendations on my login script, especially on `sessionCheck.php` security and corrections. I am not a perofessional coder yet :) but trying hard and learning very fast, so please dont yell on me, and if possible show your recommendations with examples, Thanks

Here is my login handler class which is doing all queries simple:

> LoginHandler.php

```
class LoginHandler {

    function runBaseQuery($sql, $args) {
        global $pdo;
        if (!$args){
             return $pdo->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }
        }

        if(!empty($resultset)) {
            return $resultset;
        }
    }

    function bindQueryParams($sql, $args){
        global $pdo;
        if (!$args){
             return $pdo->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

> Auth.php

```
require_once "../db.php";
require "LoginHandler.php";
class Auth {
    function getMemberByUsername($username) {
        global $pdo;
        $Lhandle = new LoginHandler();
        $sql = "Select * from users where username = ?";
        $result = $Lhandle->runBaseQuery($sql,  array($username));
        return $result;
    }

    function getTokenByUsername($username,$expired) {
        global $pdo;
        $Lhandle = new LoginHandler();
        $sql = "Select * from Auth_tokens where username = ? and is_expired = ?";
        $result = $Lhandle->runBaseQuery($sql, array($username, $expired));
        return $result;
    }

    function markAsExpired($tokenId) {
        global $pdo;
        $Lhandle = new LoginHandler();
        $sql = "UPDATE Auth_tokens SET is_expired = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $expired = 1;
        $result = $Lhandle->bindQueryParams($sql, array($expired, $tokenId));
        return $result;
    }

    function insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date) {
        global $pdo;
        $Lhandle = new LoginHandler();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Auth_tokens (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $result = $Lhandle->bindQueryParams($sql, array($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date));
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

> Util.php

```
class Util {
    public function getToken($length)
    {
        $token = "";
        $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $codeAlphabet .= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $codeAlphabet .= "0123456789";
        $max = strlen($codeAlphabet) - 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
            $token .= $codeAlphabet[$this->cryptoRandSecure(0, $max)];
        }
        return $token;
    }

    public function cryptoRandSecure($min, $max)
    {
        $range = $max - $min;
        if ($range < 1) {
            return $min; // not so random...
        }
        $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
        $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
        $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
        $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
        do {
            $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
            $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
        } while ($rnd >= $range);
        return $min + $rnd;
    }

    public function redirect($url) {
        header("Location:" . $url);
        exit();
    }

    public function clearAuthCookie() {
        if (isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) {
            setcookie("member_login", "");
        }
        if (isset($_COOKIE["random_password"])) {
            setcookie("random_password", "");
        }
        if (isset($_COOKIE["random_selector"])) {
            setcookie("random_selector", "");
        }
    }
}
```

> sessionCheck.php

```
require_once "Auth.php";
require_once "Util.php";

$auth = new Auth();
$util = new Util();

// Get Current date, time
$current_time = time();
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $current_time);

// Set Cookie expiration for 1 month
$cookie_expiration_time = $current_time + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60);  // for 1 month

$isLoggedIn = false;

// Check if loggedin session and redirect if session exists
if(!empty($_SESSION["uid"])) {
    $isLoggedIn = true;
}
// Check if loggedin session exists
else if(!empty($_COOKIE["member_login"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["random_password"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["random_selector"])) {
    // Initiate auth token verification directive to false
    $isPasswordVerified = false;
    $isSelectorVerified = false;
    $isExpiryDateVerified = false;

    // Get token for username
    $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($_COOKIE["member_login"],0);

    // Validate random password cookie with database
    if(password_verify($_COOKIE["random_password"], $userToken[0]["password_hash"])) {
        $isPasswordVerified = true;
    }

    // Validate random selector cookie with database
    if(password_verify($_COOKIE["random_selector"], $userToken[0]["selector_hash"])) {
        $isSelectorVerified = true;
    }

    // check cookie expiration by date
    if($userToken[0]["expiry_date"] >= $current_date) {
        $isExpiryDareVerified = true;
    }

    // Redirect if all cookie based validation retuens true
    // Else, mark the token as expired and clear cookies
    if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"]) && $isPasswordVerified && $isSelectorVerified && $isExpiryDareVerified) {
        $isLoggedIn = true;
    } else {
        if(!empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
            $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
        }
        // clear cookies
        $util->clearAuthCookie();
    }
}
```

> And finally login.php

```
require_once "../db.php";
require_once "../includes/functions.php";

require_once "Auth.php";
require_once "Util.php";

$auth = new Auth();
$Lhandle = new LoginHandler();
$util = new Util();

require_once "sessionCheck.php";

if ($isLoggedIn) {
    $util->redirect("dashboard.php");
}

if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $isAuthenticated = false;

    $kulladi = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    $sifre = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    $furl = test_input(base64_decode($_POST["refurl"]));

    // Validate the username.   
    if (empty($kulladi)) {
        $message[] = 'Please provide a username.';
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $kulladi)) {
        $message[] = 'The username contains invalid characters.';
    } else {
        $username = test_input($kulladi);
    }

    // Validate the password.
    if (empty($sifre)) {
        $message[] = 'Empty password field.';
    } else {
        $password = test_input($sifre);
    }

    // Validate if referer url set.
    if (isset($_POST['refurl']) && !empty($_POST['refurl'])) {
        $refurl = $furl;
    } else {
        $refurl = 'dashboard.php';
    } 

    if(empty($message)){
        if($user = $auth->getMemberByUsername($username)){
            if(password_verify($password, $user[0]["password"])) {
            $isAuthenticated = true;
                $_SESSION["uid"] = $user[0]["uid"];
                $_SESSION["username"] = $user[0]["username"];

                // Set Auth Cookies if 'Remember Me' checked
                if (!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
                    setcookie("member_login", $username, $cookie_expiration_time);

                    $random_password = $util->getToken(16);
                    setcookie("random_password", $random_password, $cookie_expiration_time);

                    $random_selector = $util->getToken(32);
                    setcookie("random_selector", $random_selector, $cookie_expiration_time);

                    $random_password_hash = password_hash($random_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $random_selector_hash = password_hash($random_selector, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                    $expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $cookie_expiration_time);

                    // mark existing token as expired
                    $userToken = $auth->getTokenByUsername($username, 0);
                    if (!empty($userToken[0]["id"])) {
                        $auth->markAsExpired($userToken[0]["id"]);
                    }
                    // Insert new token
                    $auth->insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date);
                } else {
                    $util->clearAuthCookie();
                }
                $util->redirect($refurl);
            }else{
                $message[] = "invalid user password";
            }
        }else{
            $message[] = "invalid user logins";
        }
    }
}
```

> And html codes in login.php

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="frmLogin">
    <div class="error-message">
 <?php if(isset($message)) {?>
 <?php echo implode('<br/>', $message); ?>
 </div>
 <?php } else{ ?>
   <div class="success-message">
    You have successfully created your account.
    <br/>Would you like to <a href="#">login</a> now?
   </div>
 <?php } ?>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div>
            <label for="login">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="username" type="text"
                value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { echo $_COOKIE["member_login"]; } ?>"
                class="input-field">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="password" type="password"
                value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])) { echo $_COOKIE["password"]; } ?>"
                class="input-field">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> checked
                <?php } ?> /> <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-group">
        <div>
   <?php if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){ ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="refurl" value="<?php echo base64_encode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); ?>" />
   <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="form-submit-button"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And This is the function used for filter inputs.
Note: didnt filter all inputs yet, but will.

```
function test_input($data) {
    $data = filter_var(trim($data), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, does the code work as expected?

Comment: FYI, `date()`'s default second parameter is `time()`.

Comment: @mickmackusa to find `date()` and `time()` and compare with cookie expiry time `userToken[0]["expiry_date"] >= $current_date`

Comment: Ah yes, I see now that you use time twice.  Something else... `isset($_POST['refurl'])` is not needed if followed by `!empty()`.

Comment: For one, you don't need nor should you be using that `test_input()` function with those functions in there. They don't do much to prevent a potential SQL injection. A prepared statement will take care of that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I use prepare statement in `LoginHandler.php` and `Auth.php` Do I need to use bindParam ?

Comment: I noticed that you are using a prepared statement. I just wonder why you have that `test_input()` function. It doesn't help at all. It isn't even safe. You'd probably be doing more harm than good for passwords / usernames.

Comment: its a routine of me :) will remove test_input and use `htmlspecialchars` or `sanitize_string` if needed now on. actualy I was thinking to post in stackoverflow but code was to long so I just changed to global connect

Comment: About your *"but keep getting errors on it, so I changed it to global $pdo;"* - I am wondering why you posted your question in code review. If this is about code not working, then it should be moved/migrated over to Stack Overflow.

Comment: its working fine now, there was a few worthless functions in class I removed them all and droped two function so all queries on two functions now.

Comment: _"...and use htmlspecialchars or sanitize_string"_ - It's better to store the data "as is" and then use the correct escape function when you fetch and _use_ the data. Like using `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS. Different types of output can require different types of escaping.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for point I do that in both insert and select, but didnt know its not importand in insert part will remove htmlspecialchars too. I am afraid of sessionCheck.php getting parameters from cookies on user return and login in, I need to know if sessionCheck.php is safe ? I added brute force check login too.